# how to get around the fact that the sprite can move too fast

Tags: pygame

I'm making a platform game and the problem is that the sprite can move too fast due to acceleration and this causes some problems in my code
for example. If the sprite bottom right touches a wall then it will do something like setting acceleration to 0. if the sprite goes too fast and goes inside the floor for any certain amount of time, it will count and causes weird movement

here is the main part of my code

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image=pygame.image.load("rectmo.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (25,100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.rect.width/2,self.rect.height/2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2)
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)
        self.test= self.rect.inflate(0,+1)

    def update(self):

        #controls
        user_input=pygame.key.get_pressed()

        self.acc.x = 0
        if user_input[pygame.K_d]:
            self.acc.x=player_acc
        if user_input[pygame.K_a]:
            self.acc.x=-player_acc

        #adds Friction    
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * player_friction
        #applying accelerating equation
        self.vel.x = self.vel.x * 0.95 + self.acc.x
        self.vel.y += self.acc.y
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        #stops sprite from moving through walls
        on_ground = False
        right=[self.rect.midright,self.rect.bottomright,self.rect.topright]
        left=[self.rect.midleft,self.rect.bottomleft,self.rect.topleft]
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect)== True:
                for point in right:
                    if wall.rect.collidepoint(point):
                        if self.vel.x > 0:
                            self.rect.right=wall.rect.left
                            self.test.right=wall.rect.left
                            self.vel.x=0
                            self.pos = vec(self.rect.center)
                for point in left:
                    if wall.rect.collidepoint(point):
                        if self.vel.x < 0:
                            self.rect.left=wall.rect.right
                            self.test.left=wall.rect.right
                            self.vel.x=0
                            self.pos = vec(self.rect.center)
                if self.vel.y < 0:
                    self.rect.top=wall.rect.bottom
                    self.test.top=wall.rect.bottom
                    self.vel.y=0
                    self.pos = vec(self.rect.center)

            #testing if a pixel below is a wall    
            if self.test.colliderect(wall.rect):
                on_ground = True
                if self.vel.y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom=wall.rect.top
                    self.vel.y=0
                    self.pos = vec(self.rect.center)

        if on_ground:
            self.acc.y=0
            if user_input[pygame.K_w]:
                self.vel.y=-20
        else:
            self.acc.y = player_grav

        self.test.center=self.pos
```

and this is the whole code for testing (The sprite is just a rectangle)

```
import os
import pygame
import time
import random
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image=pygame.image.load("rectmo.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (25,100))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.rect.width/2,self.rect.height/2)
        self.pos = vec(WIDTH/2,HEIGHT/2)
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)
        self.test= self.rect.inflate(0,+1)

    def update(self):

        #controls
        user_input=pygame.key.get_pressed()

        self.acc.x = 0
        if user_input[pygame.K_d]:
            self.acc.x=player_acc
        if user_input[pygame.K_a]:
            self.acc.x=-player_acc

        #adds Friction    
        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * player_friction
        #applying accelerating equation
        self.vel.x = self.vel.x * 0.95 + self.acc.x
        self.vel.y += self.acc.y
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        #stops sprite from moving through walls
        on_ground = False
        right=[self.rect.midright,self.rect.bottomright,self.rect.topright]
        left=[self.rect.midleft,self.rect.bottomleft,self.rect.topleft]
        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect)== True:
                for point in right:
                    if wall.rect.collidepoint(point):
                        if self.vel.x > 0:
                            self.rect.right=wall.rect.left
                            self.test.right=wall.rect.left
                            self.vel.x=0
                            self.pos = vec(self.rect.center)
                for point in left:
                    if wall.rect.collidepoint(point):
                        if self.vel.x < 0:
                            self.rect.left=wall.rect.right
                            self.test.left=wall.rect.right
                            self.vel.x=0
                            self.pos = vec(self.rect.center)
                if self.vel.y < 0:
                    self.rect.top=wall.rect.bottom
                    self.test.top=wall.rect.bottom
                    self.vel.y=0
                    self.pos = vec(self.rect.center)

            #testing if a pixel below is a wall    
            if self.test.colliderect(wall.rect):
                on_ground = True
                if self.vel.y > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom=wall.rect.top
                    self.vel.y=0
                    self.pos = vec(self.rect.center)

        if on_ground:
            self.acc.y=0
            if user_input[pygame.K_w]:
                self.vel.y=-20
        else:
            self.acc.y = player_grav

        self.test.center=self.pos


class Wall(object):
    def __init__(self,wx,wy):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect= pygame.Rect(wx,wy,30,30)
    def reset_wall(self):
        self.active = False


os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption('A Game')
WIDTH = 1366
HEIGHT= 768
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
walls=[]
player_grav=0.98
player_acc=0.5
player_friction=-0.02
rectmo=player()
main_colour=(0,0,0)
colour=main_colour
wall_colour=(255,255,255)
current_score=0

levels= [['WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW',
   'W  E                                         W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W             WWWWWWWWW                      W',
   'W             W                              W',
   'W             W                              W',
   'W             W                 W            W',
   'W             W                 W            W',
   'W             W                 W            W',
   'W             W                 W            W',
   'W             WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                     WWWWWWWW',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'W                                            W',
   'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW',
 ]]

x=y=0
level=random.choice(levels)
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col=='W':
            Wall(x,y)
        if col=='E':
            end_rect=pygame.Rect(x,y,30,30)
        x += 30
    y+=30
    x=0

rectmo.rect.x=500
rectmo.rect.y=500


running=True

while running==True:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    rectmo.update()










    if running==True:
        screen.fill(main_colour)
        for wall in walls:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, wall_colour,wall.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),end_rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,colour,rectmo.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),rectmo.test)

        all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        all_sprites_list.add(rectmo)
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is going to depend on how you want your program to work. You could just cap the velocity at a maximum value (terminal velocity exists even for falling objects after all.) I'm not sure what the rectangle is meant to represent you could have the keyboard control velocity instead of acceleration and just use a constant speed?

```
velocity = max(maxVelocity, velocityCalculation())
```